# Simple ESP32 replacement for ESP8266 HTTPUpdateServer

Tags: platformio, arduino-esp32

I have been using ESP8266's for a while now and am now trying ESP32. I have tried to find a drop in replacement for the ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer. I normally use:

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer httpUpdater;

const char* update_path = "/firmware";
const char* update_username = "admin";
const char* update_password = "password";

void setup() {
  httpUpdater.setup(&server, update_path, update_username, update_password);
}

Void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

How do I do the equivalent for ESP32? Every example I have seen seems to only have much more elaborate implementations which is unnecessary for my needs as I don't need security or extra checks.

Comment: Have you seen the ESP32 [WebUpdater](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPUpdateServer/examples/WebUpdater/WebUpdater.ino) example? It is not direct drop in, but is as abstract as the ESP8266 example in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! I had looked at other examples in the core that were much more complicated. I missed that one. That's what I am after.